# How do you write a function that has a class name and returns a array of strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Write a function that takes one or more class names as a parameter and returns an array of strings, where each string is the inner text content of an anchor tag in the current document that have any of the given classes

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one:

```
<a class="one" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a class="two" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a class="one" href="#">Link 3</a>
<a class="one" href="#">Link 4</a>
<a class="two" href="#">Link 5</a>
<a class="two" href="#">Link 6</a>
<a class="one" href="#">Link 7</a>

<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

and JS

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
var className = "one";
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    find(className);
});


function find(str) {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName(str);
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTextsFromLinks(...classes) {
  let resultArr = [];
  for(let class of classes) {
     for(let link of document.querySelectorAll(`.${class}`)) {
      resultArr.push(link.innerText);
    }
  }
  return resultArr;
}
```

Maybe this will work.